# Go slice element replaced by last element

Tags: arrays, go, slice

My problem is the answer should has [1 1 2 2], but it got [1 1 2 3].
I debuged this code, found that in that loop, [1 1 2 2] was appended to the array firstly, but it changed to [1 1 2 3] in next loop.
I don't understand why, the log which started with 'D', the elements in this array changed in next loop.
Here is my code:
https://play.golang.org/p/X_CU8GlMOqf

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 1, 2, 2, 3}
    result := subsetsWithDup(nums)
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func subsetsWithDup(nums []int) [][]int {
    result := [][]int{{}, nums}
    for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
        if i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i-1] {
            continue
        }
        for j := 1; j < len(nums); j++ {
            result = append(result, dsf(nums, []int{nums[i]}, i+1, j)...)
        }
    }
    return result
}

func dsf(nums []int, set []int, start int, length int) [][]int {
    result := [][]int{}
    if len(set) == length {
        return append(result, set)
    }
    for i := start; i < len(nums); i++ {
        if i != start && nums[i] == nums[i-1] {
            continue
        }
        if len(set) == 3 {
            fmt.Printf("A %v %p\n", result, &result)
        }
        tmp := set[:]
        tmp = append(tmp, nums[i])
        if len(set) == 3 {
            fmt.Printf("B %v %p %v %p\n", tmp, &tmp, result, &result)
        }
        result = append(result, dsf(nums, tmp, i+1, length)...)
        if len(tmp) == 4 {
            fmt.Printf("C %v %p %v %p\n", tmp, &tmp, result, &result)
            for _, r := range result {
                fmt.Printf("D %v %p\n", r, &r)
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

```sh
A [] 0xc000004960
B [1 1 2 2] 0xc0000049c0 [] 0xc000004960
C [1 1 2 2] 0xc0000049c0 [[1 1 2 2]] 0xc000004960
D [1 1 2 2] 0xc000004ae0
A [[1 1 2 2]] 0xc000004960
B [1 1 2 3] 0xc000004b60 [[1 1 2 3]] 0xc000004960
C [1 1 2 3] 0xc000004b60 [[1 1 2 3] [1 1 2 3]] 0xc000004960
D [1 1 2 3] 0xc000004ca0
D [1 1 2 3] 0xc000004ca0
A [] 0xc000004da0
B [1 2 2 3] 0xc000004de0 [] 0xc000004da0
C [1 2 2 3] 0xc000004de0 [[1 2 2 3]] 0xc000004da0
D [1 2 2 3] 0xc000004f00
```

Comment: Read up on what a slice is (https://blog.golang.org/slices, https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types): you have multiple slices that may be using the same underlying array.

Comment: @JimB As you can see, first time the slice is [0xc000004ae0], in the next loop, it changed to [0xc000004ca0, 0xc000004ca0]. and all the variables was created inside the loop. If the element is same underlying, the address should not change I think.

Comment: There is a difference between the address of the _slice header_ and the address of the _backing array_. The easiest way to see this is the print the address of the first element of the slice rather than the address of the slice itself with `fmt.Printf("%p", &r[0])`. Check out the "Slice Internals" section of https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro for a refresher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to copy a slice with:

```
tmp := set[:]
```

This does not copy the slice, it re-uses the original slice.  It has the same effect as `tmp := set`.  You can use:

```
tmp := append([]int(nil), set...)
```

if you like.  [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/8I0ss-WkWT3) is your program with this change, and all the extra debug commented out.